# Looking for a PDF file parser

Tags: c#, regex, delphi, pdf, unicode

Does anyone know of a PDF file parser that I could use to pull out sections of text from the plaintext pdf file?  Specifially I want a way to be able to reliably pull out the section of text specific to annotations?

Delphi, C# RegEx I dont mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PDF File Parser](http://www.xtractpro.com/articles/PDF-File-Parser.aspx) article on xactpro seems to be exactly what you need. It explains the format of the PDF and comes with full source code for a parser (and another project for visualisation of the model).

The parser uses format-specific terms, but you could easily use the visualiser to learn what to look for.

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Comment: @automatic - It looks like the entire site is down

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at Xpdf (http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it supports the functionality you need, but we've been using [abcPDF](http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#pd) with some success.

Comment: I don't think abcPDF supports parsing.

Comment: @Richard Szalay, I wasn't sure.  The feature matrix says it supports reading pdfs, but whether it goes you an object model in the api to accesss parts of the pdf is something I can't say for certain.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to reject it's advertised feature set :) It didn't support it when I used it last, but it's writing capabilities certainly did the job well.

Comment: ABCpdf does expose an object model, it's what they call Atoms.

Answer (score 1):

check out pdfbox

Answer (score 1):

abcPDF does let you extract annotations, they have a very good section in the help for it, but the code to handle it is generally :

```
    for (int objectIndex = 0; objectIndex < theDoc.ObjectSoup.Count; objectIndex++)
        {
            try
            {
                IndirectObject element = theDoc.ObjectSoup.ElementAt(objectIndex);

                string elementType = element.GetType().ToString();
                switch (elementType)
                {
                    case "WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Objects.Annotation":
                       //process the annotation, which could be all kinds of stuff
                        WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Objects.Annotation annotation = (WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Objects.Annotation)element; 

                        ProcessAnnotation(annotation);
```

...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know all the features of these PDF parsers, but Aspose has a pretty comprehensive one.  We did, unfortunately, come across two bugs, and I've been waiting a long time for them to be fixed.

ITextSharp seems to be the most common open source PDF parser for .Net.